# Ping-Pong Movement with a starting point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Note:** `objectSpawns[]` contains instantiated `GameObject`s, all set with random X Position(-2.8f, 2.8f) Y positions stacked along y-axis

**What's Happening:** All Instantiated objects are moving correctly, but it is ignoring the initial offset on the X Position. So they are all moving on the same X position back and forth, when I am trying to get them to move back and forth with their initial X offset.

```
void Update()
{
    //PingPong between 0 and 1
    float time = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 1);
    //transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(pointA, pointB, time);

    for (int i = 0; i < objectSpawns.Length; i++)
    {
        pointA = new Vector3(-3.8f, objectSpawns[i].transform.localPosition.y, 0);
        pointB = new Vector3(3.8f, objectSpawns[i].transform.localPosition.y, 0);
        objectSpawns[i].transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(pointA, pointB, time);
    }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be no mention of any offset in the code you pasted. Are you sure this bug is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that all your Objects are moving with the-same position instead of starting the movement from the current position. The `Mathf.PingPong` function is not really meant to be used with a starting position. It's made to blindly move between two values back an forth without a starting position.

To make GameObject move back and forth, use `Vector3 Lerp(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float t)` + coroutine. The [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) explains how it works well but to simply it, it returns `a` when `0` is passed to `t`, middle point between `a` and `b` when `0.5` is passed to `t` and `b` when `1` is passed to `t`.

With this, you can use a coroutine function to move GameObject back and forth and be able to supply where the movement starts.

```
public GameObject[] objectSpawns;
public float speed = 1.19f;

Vector3 pointA = new Vector3(3.49f, 29.8f, -41.2f);
Vector3 pointB = new Vector3(13.91f, 29.8f, -41.2f);

void Start()
{
    PingPongAllObjects();
}

void PingPongAllObjects()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < objectSpawns.Length; i++)
    {
        StartCoroutine(PingPongEachObject(objectSpawns[i].transform, pointA, pointB));
    }
}

IEnumerator PingPongEachObject(Transform targetObject, Vector3 PosA, Vector3 PosB)
{
    while (true)
    {
        //Move to B and wait for the Move to finish
        yield return moveToX(targetObject, PosB, speed);
        //Move to A and wait for the Move to finish
        yield return moveToX(targetObject, PosA, speed);
    }
}

IEnumerator moveToX(Transform targetObject, Vector3 toPosition, float speed)
{
    float startTime;
    // Total distance between the markers.
    float journeyLength;
    startTime = Time.time;

    //Get the current position of the object to be moved
    Vector3 startPos = targetObject.position;
    // Calculate the journey length.
    journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(startPos, toPosition);


    if (startPos == toPosition)
        yield break;

    while (true)
    {
        // Distance moved = time * speed.
        float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;

        // Fraction of journey completed = current distance divided by total distance.
        float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;

        // Set our position as a fraction of the distance between the markers.
        targetObject.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, toPosition, fracJourney);

        //Exit if lerp time reaches 1
        if (fracJourney >= 1)
            yield break;

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much couldn't figure it out